# How do I access BOR macros from a class?

Tags: object, workflow, abap

If you're used to accessing BOR objects via the macros in include `<CNTN01>,` you may attempt to do this within the ABAP OO context as well.

Due to the strong typing restrictions of ABAP OO this is not possible.

What is the alternative?

Comment: Another simple one that I got tired of googling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the "Macros" Section of your ABAP Class include the following:

```
include: <cntn02>,
         <cntn03>.
```